# How to fix `libdropbox_apex.so` problem with latest Dropbox?

Tags: permissions, python, dropbox, caja

I have installed `caja-dropbox` package on my Ubuntu MATE 19.04 system as simple as `sudo apt-get install caja-dropbox` but it does not start from GUI and continuously asks me about Caja restart.

When starting from the terminal it shows the following error messages:

```
$ caja-dropbox start -i
Starting Dropbox...dropbox: locating interpreter
dropbox: logging to /tmp/dropbox-antifreeze-lmlIjG
dropbox: initializing
dropbox: initializing python 3.7.2
dropbox: setting program path '/var/lib/dropbox/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-81.4.195/dropbox'
dropbox: setting home path '/var/lib/dropbox/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-81.4.195'
dropbox: setting python path '/var/lib/dropbox/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-81.4.195:/var/lib/dropbox/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-81.4.195/python-packages-37.zip'
dropbox: python initialized
dropbox: running dropbox
dropbox: setting args
dropbox: applying overrides
dropbox: running main script
dropbox: load fq extension '/var/lib/dropbox/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-81.4.195/cryptography.hazmat.bindings._constant_time.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/var/lib/dropbox/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-81.4.195/cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/var/lib/dropbox/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-81.4.195/cryptography.hazmat.bindings._padding.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/var/lib/dropbox/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-81.4.195/psutil._psutil_linux.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/var/lib/dropbox/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-81.4.195/psutil._psutil_posix.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/var/lib/dropbox/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-81.4.195/linuxffi.pthread._linuxffi_pthread.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/var/lib/dropbox/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-81.4.195/cpuid.compiled._cpuid.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/var/lib/dropbox/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-81.4.195/tornado.speedups.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/var/lib/dropbox/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-81.4.195/apex._apex.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dropbox/client/main.pyc", line 18, in <module>
  File "dropbox/client/features/catalina_migration/catalina_migration_controller.pyc", line 19, in <module>
  File "dropbox/client/features/catalina_migration/catalina_account_context.pyc", line 13, in <module>
  File "dropbox/client/features/catalina_migration/alert_dialog.pyc", line 10, in <module>
  File "dropbox/client/features/file_locking/base_file_locking_alert.pyc", line 14, in <module>
  File "dropbox/client/features/legacy_ui_launcher.pyc", line 21, in <module>
  File "dropbox/client/configuration/manager.pyc", line 45, in <module>
  File "dropbox/client/configuration/utils.pyc", line 27, in <module>
  File "dropbox/client/notifications/loud_notifications/do_not_disturb/model.pyc", line 51, in <module>
  File "ui/common/preferences.pyc", line 21, in <module>
  File "dropbox/client/authentication/manager.pyc", line 36, in <module>
  File "dropbox/client/authentication/control_flow_helpers.pyc", line 3, in <module>
  File "dropbox/client/high_trace.pyc", line 53, in <module>
  File "dropbox/client/logging/dbxlog_logger.pyc", line 11, in <module>
  File "apex/dbxlog.pyc", line 14, in <module>
  File "<_bootstrap_overrides>", line 153, in load_module
ImportError: libdropbox_apex.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
!! dropbox: fatal python exception:
['Traceback (most recent call last):\n', ' File "dropbox/client/main.pyc", line 18, in <module>\n', ' File "dropbox/client/features/catalina_migration/catalina_migration_controller.pyc", line 19, in <module>\n', ' File "dropbox/client/features/catalina_migration/catalina_account_context.pyc", line 13, in <module>\n', ' File "dropbox/client/features/catalina_migration/alert_dialog.pyc", line 10, in <module>\n', ' File "dropbox/client/features/file_locking/base_file_locking_alert.pyc", line 14, in <module>\n', ' File "dropbox/client/features/legacy_ui_launcher.pyc", line 21, in <module>\n', ' File "dropbox/client/configuration/manager.pyc", line 45, in <module>\n', ' File "dropbox/client/configuration/utils.pyc", line 27, in <module>\n', ' File "dropbox/client/notifications/loud_notifications/do_not_disturb/model.pyc", line 51, in <module>\n', ' File "ui/common/preferences.pyc", line 21, in <module>\n', ' File "dropbox/client/authentication/manager.pyc", line 36, in <module>\n', ' File "dropbox/client/authentication/control_flow_helpers.pyc", line 3, in <module>\n', ' File "dropbox/client/high_trace.pyc", line 53, in <module>\n', ' File "dropbox/client/logging/dbxlog_logger.pyc", line 11, in <module>\n', ' File "apex/dbxlog.pyc", line 14, in <module>\n', ' File "<_bootstrap_overrides>", line 153, in load_module\n', 'ImportError: libdropbox_apex.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory\n'] (error 3)
```

What should I do to get Dropbox working again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problematic library `libdropbox_apex.so` is located in the `/var/lib/dropbox/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-81.4.195` folder.

But there is one strange thing here - it do not have executable permissions. This is how it differs from other libraries:

```
$ ls -al libdropbox_apex.so
-rw------- 1 root root 7138143 сен 18 10:24 libdropbox_apex.so
```

To fix the problem we need to set read and execution permissions for this file:

```
sudo chmod a+rx /var/lib/dropbox/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64*/libdropbox_apex.so
```

**Update 20191109**: the number of problematic libraries - increased to 2, now with Dropbox 84.4.170 we need to change permission of `libdropbox_sqlite_ext.so` too:

```
sudo chmod a+rx /var/lib/dropbox/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64*/libdropbox_sqlite_ext.so
```

and then start it again from GUI or with `caja-dropbox start -i`.

---

Notes:

1) this method is also applicable for 16.04 LTS, 18.04 LTS and 
19.10.
2) I reported this to LaunchPad as [bug 1845876](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1845876).
3) [Ticket on dropbox support site](https://dropbox.zendesk.com/hc/requests/9797860) was created on 20191005 but is still not resolved.